# How do you pad the StringBuilder?

Tags: scala, collections, stringbuilder, fill

I build a string adding chars to the end and trimming the end incidentially. Incidentially, I need to add n identical c-chars to the end. How do you do that, 1 to n sb.append(c)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation for StringBuilder](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder@padTo(len:Int,elem:A):scala.collection.mutable.IndexedSeq[A]):

> def padTo(len: Int, elem: A): IndexedSeq[A]
>
> [use case]
>   A copy of this string builder with an element value appended until a given target length is reached.
>
> len        the target length
>   elem     the padding value
>
> returns
>   a new string builder consisting of all elements of this string builder followed by the minimal number of occurrences of elem so that the resulting string builder has a length of at least len.

If you really need to add another `n` characters (not usually what's meant by `pad`, then use `len` as `sb.length + n`